# Implement io.WriterTo with JSON

Tags: json, go, interface

I found this cool interface recently, `io.WriterTo`:

https://godocs.io/io#WriterTo

I would like to implement it for some JSON objects. I was able to make this:

```
package calendar

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/json"
   "io"
)

type date struct {
   Month int
   Day int
}

func (d date) WriteTo(w io.Writer) (int64, error) {
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   err := json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(d)
   if err != nil {
      return 0, err
   }
   return buf.WriteTo(w)
}
```

But I think it's not ideal, as it makes a copy of the object in memory, before sending to the Writer. Is it possible to write directly, but also know how many bytes were written?

Comment: in your example you just delegate for the `bytes.Buffer`. in terms of applicability I think this interface allows you implements custom way to orchestrate the write flow. example: implements cache to not always need to compute the encode.

Answer (score 2):

To write directly, create an io.Writer wrapper that counts the bytes written:

```
type countingWriter struct {
    n int64
    w io.Writer
}

func (cw *countingWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := cw.w.Write(p)
    cw.n += int64(n)
    return n, err
}
```

Change the WriteTo method to encode to a writer where the writer is the wrapper on the argument. Return the count of bytes and error when done.

```
func (d date) WriteTo(w io.Writer) (int64, error) {
    cw := &countingWriter{w: w}
    err := json.NewEncoder(cw).Encode(d)
    return cw.n, err
}
```

[Run an example on the the Go PlayGround](https://go.dev/play/p/KiJNnkdFss6)

Comment: this is a cool example. For a better quality answer would you mind to describle the applicability of this code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write directly, but also know how many bytes were written?

Coincidentally, it is what exercise 7.2 of the book *The Go Programming Language* is about. The exercise consists of implementing a function with the signature:

```
func CountingWriter(w io.Writer) (io.Writer, *int64)
```

The returned pointer to `int64` must contain at any moment the number of bytes written to the returned `io.Writer`. Essentially, the returned `io.Writer` is a [*decorator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) as it enhances the functionality of the initial `io.Writer` by updating a byte counter.

First, let's create the type `writerFunc`, which has the same parametrization as the only method of [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer), `Write`:

```
type writerFunc func([]byte) (int, error)
```

Then, define the method `Write(p []byte) (int, error)` on `writerFunc`:

```
func (wf writerFunc) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return wf(p)
}
```

This way, `writerFunc` satisfies `io.Writer` and serves as an adapter for any `func([]byte) (int, error)` into an `io.Writer` – i.e., we can wrap a `func([]byte) (int, error)` in a `writerFunc` whenever an `io.Writer` is required.

Finally, the `CountingWriter` decorating function we are looking for:

```
func CountingWriter(w io.Writer) (io.Writer, *int64) {
    count := new(int64)
    writeAndCount := func(data []byte) (int, error) {
        bytes, err := w.Write(data)
        *count += int64(bytes)
        return bytes, err
    }
    return writerFunc(writeAndCount), count
}
```

Note the last `return` statement: the closure `writeAndCount` is wrapped in a `writerFunc`. This works because the closure's type is `func([]byte) (int, error)` as well. As we have seen above, `writerFunc` satisfies `io.Writer`, which the caller of this function eventually receives.